# How do I fix the "unknown directive "accesslog" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:28" error?

Tags: nginx, configuration

```
[root@mail ~]# strace -o ~/nginx-strace.log chroot /chroot/nginx /usr/sbin/nginx

nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "accesslog" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:28
```

What might be causing this problem and how would I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Edit your /etc/nginx/nginx.conf - change line 28 from `accesslog` to [`access_log`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLogModule#access_log) (note the underscore).

As per the error, there is no directive 'accesslog' - so nginx failed to load the configuration.